# How can MS Gothic font be installed on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server?

Tags: linux, rhel7

I am using xdocreport java library to convert .docx to .pdf, conversion is incorrect because my OS is missing some required fonts (MS Gothic). How can I install it on my OS? It's version is

NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.7 (Maipo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists an answer on how to install TrueType fonts on CentOS 7 here:
 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/415246/how-to-install-fonts-for-centos-7/415249

However, you cannot copy that font to a server without licensing it. More information [here](https://catalog.monotype.com/font/microsoft-corporation/ms-gothic/regular)

Comment: Seems that Microsoft True type fonts does not include Ms Gothic and does not support Chinese symbols